# Button to match height of field?

Tags: css

I am trying to get some buttons to be the same height as a field...
I must be missing something obvious at the moment because the heights are different on each browser: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v6pLqbfz/)

```css
input {
    font-size:16px;
    padding:8px;
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow:inset 0 1px 3px #ddd;
    border-radius:0px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    line-height:20px;
}

button {
    font-size:16px;
    display:inline-block;
    background:#ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    cursor:pointer; color:#b2b2b2;
    font-weight:700; padding:8px;
    line-height:20px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<button>-</button><input type="text"/><button>+</button>
```

Comment: Why don't you just use bootstrap or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set height to both button and input:

```
height: 40px;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v6pLqbfz/1/

Comment: I guess this is the best option. I just don't understand why it needs a set height when all the other settings are the same....

Comment: Because font-sizes and padding are different in every browser. This all affects the height. Giving it a fixed height makes sure it renders correctly in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Try [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), wrap your content into `.container` and make it flex. Its children would be stretched vertically by height of container.

```css
.container,
.contained > * {
  box-sizing: padding-box;
}
.container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  height: 38px;
}
input,
button {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
input {
  font-size: 16px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px #ddd;
}
button {
  width: 30px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #b2b2b2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>-</button>
  <input type="text" />
  <button>+</button>
</div>
```